# Run Child's Onclick But Not Parent's Where Argument is Passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

Given some simple HTML such this, where one element has an `onclick` function and it's child also has an `onclick` function:

```
<div style='background-color:blue;width:500px;height:500px;'
    onclick='thing1();'>
    <div style='background-color:red;width:100px;height:100px;'
        onclick='thing2(57);'></div>
</div>
```

What would be the correct approach so that when a user clicks the child element, only the child's `onclick` is executed and not the parent's, but when the parent is clicked, it's `onclick` is still executed? I see that `event.stopPropagation()` would be the correct way to go, but since I'm passing an argument to the function `thing2()`, I can't seem to pass the event as well. For example:

```
function thing2(a,ev) {
    // Do something with a
    ev.stopPropagation();
    }
```

Doesn't work, failing with the error `TypeError: ev is undefined`.

JQuery is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is the first param.

```
function thing2(ev) {
  var a = ev.target
  ev.stopPropagation()
}
```

Secondly, it's best not to use `onclick=`. Instead, give your div classes or ids and do something like this:

```
<div class="thing-1" data-thingy="57">
  <div class="thing-2" data-thingy="65"></div>
</div>

<script>
  $('.thing-1').click(function (ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation()
    parseInt($(ev.target).data('thingy'), 10) // 57
  })

  $('.thing-2').click(function (ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation()
    parseInt($(ev.target).data('thingy'), 10) // 65
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed something when copying the code. See the updated HTML where the `onclick` for the child is `onclick='thing2(57)'` (the number is random).

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function on click, no event will be passed as argument and it somehow you can do that, that is not a Jquery object and that will not have `stopPropagation` property. SO you need to define jQuery click event handler for both divs, let's give them ids `div1` and `div2`.

HTML

```
<div id="div1" style='background-color:blue;width:500px;height:500px;'>
  <div id="div2" style='background-color:red;width:100px;height:100px;'></div>
</div>
```

In Javascript,

```
function thing2(ev) {
  // Do something with a
  console.log(ev);
  alert('hi2');
  ev.stopPropagation();
}

function thing1(ev) {
  // Do something with a
  alert('hi1');
}

$('#div1').click(thing1);

$('#div2').click(thing2);
```

Comment: (1) "When you call a function on click, no event will be passed as argument" ... yes it will; it is the one and only param. (2) `.stopPropagation` is a native DOM Event method, not a special offering of jQuery.

Comment: But I tried as given in question and on logging that value `ev` or`a`, it's undefined. Look at this fiddle http://jsbin.com/quyideturo/edit?html,js,output